# How to build with a Distribution profile

Tags: xcode

How do I build with a Distribution profile? I make one in the portal download it and drag it to xcode, when I drag it to xcode, it days its missing the private pair key info. Why It doesn't happen when I use the provisioning profile. When I Archive the app and build it it says 'No Valid Signing Identity found'

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "Build Settings" tab of your target application that "All", near the top, is clicked. Then go down to the section labeled "Code Signing" and choose the profiles to build with.